# Control yeelight smart bulb with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to combine flutter with yeelight to control the light through the app? Developers gave the code (https://pub.dev/packages/yeedart) but how can I combine it with ON / OFF buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's important to first read the documentation provided.

This library provides the following function for discovering:

```
final responses = await Yeelight.discover();
final response = responses.first; // or another one
```

And for subsequent connecting to the device:

```
final device = Device(
  address: InternetAddress("192.168.1.183"),
  port: 55443,
);

await device.turnOn(); // turn the device on

// set red color with smooth transition
await device.setRGB(
  color: Colors.red,
  effect: const Effect.smooth(),
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
);

await device.setBrightness(brightness: 70); // set brightness to 70 %

device.disconnect(); // always disconnect when you are done!
```

Comment: Yes, I read this but I am new at dart and flutter and I don't know how connect this to my app

Comment: I'm happy to help with that! But try to pinpoint the exact problem you're having next time you ask a question :)

Comment: ok,  its works :)